# HTML input pattern doesn't work correctly

Tags: html, input

I have a form

```
<form method="POST">
    <p><label for="id_product_phone">Phone number:</label>
        <input type="text" pattern="\+?[0-9\s\-\(\)]+" title="Invalid phone number" name="product_phone" maxlength="20" required="" id="id_product_phone"></p>
    <p><label for="id_product_productname">Product name:</label>
        <input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z]" name="product_productname" maxlength="100" required="" id="id_product_productname"></p>
    <p><label for="id_product_description">Description:</label>
        <input type="text" name="product_description" maxlength="500" id="id_product_description"></p>
    <p><label for="id_product_media">Picture:</label>
        <input type="file" name="product_media" required="" id="id_product_media"></p>
    <button type="submit">Надіслати</button>
</form>
```

and when I try to submit it says second input does not have correct data, but I write only letters what I set. Why it doesn't work? Can someone check, please?

I use Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern needs a "+" at the end, but specifying the allowed length inside the pattern also does the trick :)

This makes an input over 100 characters impossible:
*maxlength="100" pattern="[A-Za-z]+"*

This only checks the length on submit:
*pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,100}"*

*pattern="[A-Za-z]"* checks for a-z, A-Z, but a length of 1, no matter the maxlength attribute.